# Automatically store link when org-capture is called?

Tags: org-capture

I know about the `%a` template element, which inserts the stored link in the entry. I'd also like to automatically store a link whenever `org-capture` is called from within emacs (as opposed to spawning a capture window externally via `emacsclient`).

This would be useful, for example, when coding and needing to capture a task relevant to the passage of code I'm currently writing, or when I'm reading email and decide the current email needs to become a task.

When appropriate, I'd like to include the line number in the link.

Is this something that's already built in, or would it require a custom lisp function? I'm thinking I can probably advise `org-capture` to run `org-store-link` first, but perhaps there's a better idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`org-capture` already calls `org-store-link` and puts the information into a property list:

```
(plist-get org-store-link-plist :annotation)
```